# Openvpn Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to connect to a vpn provider server with openvpn 2.5.5 in my client, but I have encountered some errors while tying to login and start the session.

The connection .ovpn file has been provided by the server's owner and includes the credentials. The problem comes when I try to connect and I receive some warnings:

**Client:**
*WARNING: 'link-mtu' is used inconsistently, local='link-mtu 1560', remote='link-mtu 1544'*

**Server:**
*Option inconsistency warnings triggering disconnect due to --opt-verify'*

After googling a bit, I have found that it is possible to modify the client's .ovpn file for adding some parameters, as `link-mtu 1544` for solvig the warning, but then I obtain: *WARNING:'tun-mtu' is used inconsistently, local='tun-mtu 1500', remote='tun-mtu 1420'"*, which could be solved with `tun-mtu 1420`, but it brings:

*Options error: only one of --tun-mtu or --link-mtu may be defined (note that --ifconfig implies --link-mtu 1500)*

So, I don't, know how to solve it, pls help.

Comment: does it work with the original file? Those sound like warnings, not errors.

Comment: Due to --opt-verify in the server side it fails